# Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Bug_authorId_key`

Tags: prisma

I am trying to implement a relation querie with Prisma ORM but this error does not allow.

My system consists in a bugtracker, where the user can report bugs. So I'm linking the User with the bugs. When I try to create a new data this error appears: "Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Bug_authorId_key`"

```js
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String 
  email String @unique
  password String
  role String @default("User")
  bugs Bug[]
  teamId Int?
  team Team? @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id])
}

model Team {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  users User[]
  admins Admin[]
}

model Admin {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String 
  email String @unique
  password String
  role String @default("Admin")
  teamId Int?
  team Team? @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id]) 
}

model Bug {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String
  description String
  status String
  authorId Int
  author User @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
}
```

```js
const bug = await prisma.bug.create({
    data: {
      title: req.body.title,
      status: req.body.status,
      description: req.body.description,
      author: {
        connect: {id: req.body.authorId}
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: You seem to have a unique constraint... How do you manage your database schema?

Comment: I'm using MySQL and it automatically puts the authorId as unique

Comment: I doubt that. How did you create the table? E.g. SQL statement

Comment: I did not created the table manually, but I can give you the statements:

-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE `Bugs` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    `status` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    `authorId` INTEGER NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- AddForeignKey
ALTER TABLE `Bugs` ADD CONSTRAINT `Bugs_authorId_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`authorId`) REFERENCES `Users`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;

Comment: The code that you have shared is working as expected for me. Have you explicitly defined a unique constraint directly on the database?